# I have trouble showing the logical implication of an absolute-value inequality.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus

In proving a property of the limit of the dot product of two functions, my vector calculus textbook asserts that $\left| {g({\bf{x}}) - {\bf{b}}} \right| < \varepsilon \Rightarrow \left| {g({\bf{x}})} \right| < \varepsilon  + \left| {\bf{b}} \right|$. However, I just can't figure out how the latter follows from the former when the only term with a defined (positive) sign is epsilon.

I'm guessing I have to use the triangle inequality, since $\left| {g({\bf{x}}) - {\bf{b}}} \right| \le \left| {g({\bf{x}})} \right| + \left| {\bf{b}} \right|$ but I can't show that the right-hand side is smaller than epsilon, which would let me prove the statement immediately.

$\left| {g({\mathbf{x}})} \right| \leqslant \left| {g({\mathbf{x}})} \right| + \left| {\mathbf{b}} \right| < \varepsilon  \leqslant \varepsilon  + \left| {\mathbf{b}} \right|$

Comment: Did you mean to write $|g(x)-b| \lt \varepsilon$ somewhere in the premise?

Comment: $|g (x)-b|$ can't imply anything.  It isn't a statement.  It's just a value.  That's like saying $3 \implies 7$ is prime.  $3$ doesn't imply anything.  It's a number, not a statement.

Comment: @fleablood you are right, my bad. I corrected it even though it has already been answered for anyone to see in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By triangle inequality, we have $$|g(x)|-|b|  \leq |g(x) - b|$$

To see this $|g(x)|=|g(x)-b+b| \leq |g(x)-b|+|b|$

Hence if $|g(x)-b| < \epsilon$, we have $|g(x)|-|b| < \epsilon$ and hence the result.